# WordPress Read More Opening As Accordion

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

My question this time around involves the WordPress "Read More" link.  I have it functioning correctly, but rather than have the Read More open a new page or Fancybox window I'd like to code it to open an accordion.  I'll have a page with 10 posts and no archive list.  There will also be no Previous or Next links.  Its just a standard 10 post list  The idea is to have each post as an accordion tab, with the text prior to the more tag showing, and when Read More is clicked it will expand that specific post.  Below is currently the code I am using for the custom loop.  Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.more-link').before('<br/>');
});
</script>
```

```php
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'news&events', 'showposts' => 10, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC')); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="newsArticle">

    <div class="newsThumb">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-featured'); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="newsPostContent">

        <div class="newsTitleDate">
            <span class="newsTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></span> <span class="newsDate"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <?php 
            global $more;
            $more = 0;
            the_content('<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/img/readMore.png" alt="Read More" />');
        ?>

    </div>


    <img class="newsDivider" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/newsDividerLine.png" alt="Divider Line" />

</div>

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success with the [Read More Right Here plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/read-more-right-here/). It's pretty slick, but it will allow the expansion of more than one post on a page. What it does is append a `<p>` tag inside the element containing your Read More link and AJAXes in the rest of the post content. You can modify it to give the inserted `<p>` a class, and amend the plugin script to hide all the others (and re-toggle the more-link text) when expanding a new post.

Alternatively, as a proof of concept, you could structure your loop to work with the jQuery UI accordion. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/SqmwM/) showing how it could be done.

You can specify what the accordion will consider the "header", and then the div element after it can contain the post content. This eliminates the need for a Read More link, as post content is already being loaded, and is just hidden by nature of the accordion.

Comment: I had thought about going the jQuery accordion route; however, as you said, that would require the post content to actually be hidden in the accordion until the header is clicked.  Not quite what I am after.  I would like for more some of the content to show and then have the full post expand when the Read More is clicked.  I also would not be able to use the excerpt as the header text preview for the accordion because it is being used in another location on the site to show a brief preview snippet of the most recent post.  It will have different text than what is needed for the 10 post page.

Comment: I will check out the plugin as well, I have not heard of it before.  It sounds like it could certainly come in useful in some situations.

Comment: Yeah, check out the `wt_rmrh-debug.js` file – it's pretty readable, and you shouldn't have too much trouble hooking in to `ExpandContent` and closing all the rest of the expanded contents.